# xref suggestions are truncated

Tags: xref

I use xref to find tags in emacs 25.

My problem is with C       defines, when there are multiple definitions. The *xref* buffer
       shows suggestions, but does not show enough text (it stops right
       after the identifier).

For example, when looking up `PRINTF`, one of the found definitions showed in the *xref* buffer
       looks like this:

```
#define PRINTF(
```

while the actual code at that location is:

```
#define PRINTF(FORMAT, args ...) printf_P(PSTR(FORMAT), ## args)
```

How do I make the *xref* buffer show the whole row in the file?

---

Edit: creating my TAGS with:

```
;; Shell command: find . -type f \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.[ch]pp' \) | etags -
(defun create-tags (dir-name)
  "Create tags file."
  (interactive "DDirectory: ")
  (shell-command
   (format "cd %s && find . -type f \\( -name \'*.[ch]\' -o -name \'*.[ch]pp\' \\) | etags -" dir-name))
  )
```

Comment: Seems like more an issue with the program used to generate the TAGS file. Are you using etags, ctags, ggtags, etc ?

Comment: @InHarmsWay Ha, that makes sense. I use `etags`, editing to add how.

Comment: If you don't like `etags`'s behavior, and you can't find a relevant flag to change it, please go ahead and file a bug report.